# Migrated form Sharepoint to SP Online Authentication fails after migration

Tags: authentication, online

We are migratetd to Sharepoint online and now my code do not work. the Authentication fails and I becom eroor and no the list of items in my API
or i can't save a new Item.

---

> 

public class SNotifications : SPConnector
{
public SNotifications()
{
credentials = new Credentials.Systems();
}
#region helpers
private const string SNOTIFICATION = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";

```
    private static Guid SNotifGuid()
    {
        return Guid.Parse(SNOTIFICATION);
    }

    private bool CanRead()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private bool CanWrite()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public RestResponse Save(MeldungDTO body, int id, bool isNew)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

        json = json.Replace(@"""id"":", @"""ID"":");
        json = json.Replace(@"""inhalt""", @"""Inhalt""");
        json = json.Replace(@"""title""", @"""Title""");
        json = json.Replace(@"""Janein""", @"""Janein""");

        json = json.Replace("{", "{\"__metadata\": { \"type\": \"SP.Data.ITListeListItem\" }, ");
        return SPSave(SNotifGuid(), json, isNew, id);
    }
    #endregion

    public IEnumerable<int> GetRecentSNotifications(int fromDays)
    {

        var iList = new List<int>();
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0 - fromDays).Date;
        var items = GetListItemsCAML(SNotifGuid(), String.Format("<View><Query><Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='Date1' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{0}</Value></Gt></Where></Query></View>", date.ToIsoString()));
        foreach (var li in items)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(li["ID"]);
            iList.Add(i);
        }
        return iList;
    }

    #region itemIO



    #endregion

    #region attachmentIO
    public RestResponse ListAttachments(int id)
    {
        return Ok(GetJsonContentFromString(SPListAttachments(SNotifGuid(), 0, 200, id)));
    }



    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadAttachments(int id, HttpRequestMessage Request)
    {
        return SPSaveAttachment(SNotifGuid(), id, Request);
    }

    #endregion

    public RestResponse Search(string SearchText, DateTime from, DateTime until, int pageSize, int startIndex, string sortingProps)
    {
        var rootFilter = new SPFilterAnd();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
        {
            rootFilter.AddItems(new SPFilterFreeSanitized(SearchText));
        }

        rootFilter.AddEqual("Path", credentials.baseUrl() + "sites/ITTest/Lists/ITListe/DispForm.aspx*");

        rootFilter.AddEqual(" JaneinOWSBOOL ", "1");
        var selectedPropList = new List<string> { "ListItemID", "Title", "InhaltOWSTEXT", "JaneinOWSBOOL", "ErstelltOWSDATE" };

        var returnString = SPSearch(sortingProps, pageSize, startIndex, rootFilter.GetFilter(), selectedPropList);
        var r = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<ResultSetObjs.RootObject>(returnString);
        var res = (from x in r.d.postquery.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results
                   select new
                   {
                       id = int.Parse(x.Cells.GetByName("ListItemID"))
                       ,
                       title = x.Cells.GetByName("Title")
                       ,
                       inhalt = x.Cells.GetByName("InhaltOWSTEXT")
                       ,
                       janein = Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells.GetByName("JaneinOWSBOOL"))
                       ,
                       date = Convert.ToDateTime(x.Cells.GetByName("ErstelltOWSDATE"))

                   }); ;
        return Ok(GetJsonContent(new
        {
            totalRows = r.d.postquery.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRows,
            table = res,
            actStartIndex = startIndex,
            actEndIndex = startIndex + res.Count()
        }));
    }
}
```

public class SPConnector
{
#region Helper

```
    protected Credentials.SPCredentials credentials = null;
    private ISet<string> ProhibitedFileExtensions = new HashSet<string> { "adp", "app", "asp", "bas", "bat", "cer", "chm", "cmd", "cnt", "com", "cpl", "crt", "csh", "der", "exe", "fxp", "gadget", "hlp", "hpj", "hta", "inf", "ins", "isp", "its", "js", "jse", "ksh", "lnk", "mad", "maf", "mag", "mam", "maq", "mar", "mas", "mat", "mau", "mav", "maw", "mda", "mdb", "mde", "mdt", "mdw", "mdz", "msc", "msh", "msh1", "msh2", "mshxml", "msh1xml", "msh2xml", "msi", "msp", "mst", "ops", "osd", "pcd", "pif", "plg", "prf", "prg", "pst", "reg", "scf", "scr", "sct", "shb", "shs", "ps1", "ps1xml", "ps2", "ps2xml", "psc1", "psc2", "tmp", "url", "vb", "vbe", "vbp", "vbs", "vsmacros", "vsw", "ws", "wsc", "wsf", "wsh", "xnk", "ade", "cla", "class", "grp", "jar", "mcf", "ocx", "pl", "xbap", "msg" };
    private readonly int MAX_LENGTH_FILENAME = 128;

    protected ListItemCollection GetListItemsCAML(Guid listGuid, string CAML)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(credentials.baseUrl()))
            {
                context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
                List aList = context.Web.Lists.GetById(listGuid);
                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                query.ViewXml = CAML;
                ListItemCollection items = aList.GetItems(query);
                context.Load(items);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                return items;
            }
        }
        catch {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected RestResponse Unauthorized()
    {
        return new RestResponse()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(""),
            Response = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
        };
    }

    protected RestResponse BadRequest(string message)
    {
        return new RestResponse()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(message),
            Response = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
        };
    }

    protected RestResponse Ok(HttpContent content)
    {
        return new RestResponse()
        {
            Content = content,//new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
            Response = HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }

    protected RestResponse Ok()
    {
        return new RestResponse()
        {
            Response = HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }

    protected HttpContent GetJsonContentFromString(string content)
    {
        return new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    }

    protected HttpContent GetJsonContent(object content)
    {
        return GetJsonContentFromString(SimpleJson.SimpleJson.SerializeObject(content));
    }

    private static string GetFormDigest(string siteUrl, NetworkCredential credential, CookieContainer cc)
    {

        try
        {

        string formDigest = null;
        string resourceUrl = siteUrl + "_api/contextinfo";
        HttpWebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(resourceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        CredentialCache credentialCacheDigest = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(resourceUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        wreq.Credentials = credentialCacheDigest;
        wreq.Method = "POST";
        wreq.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        wreq.ContentLength = 0;
        wreq.ContentType = "application/json";
        string result;
        WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wresp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var val = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(result);
        var d = val["d"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        var wi = d["GetContextWebInformation"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        formDigest = wi["FormDigestValue"].ToString();
        return formDigest;

        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
    #endregion

    protected RestResponse SPDelete(Guid typeId, int id)
    {
        var url = String.Format("_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/items({1})", typeId, id);
        string internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + url;
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", GetFormDigest(credentials.baseUrl(), credential, cookie));
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        request.Method = "DELETE";
        request.Headers.Add("If-Match", "*");
        request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8";
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        HttpWebResponse responseInternal = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        return Ok(response.Content);
    }

    protected String SPSearchGet(Guid type, IEnumerable<string> properties)
    {
        string url = String.Format("_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/Items", type);
        string internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + url;
        //internalUrl += "?$filter=ID eq " + id.ToString() + "&$select=&selectedProps='Attachments,AttachmentFiles'&$expand=AttachmentFiles";
        internalUrl += "?$select=" + String.Join(",", properties);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Accept = @"application/json;odata=verbose";
        HttpWebResponse responseInternal = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseInternal.GetResponseStream());
        var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return objText;
    }

    protected String SPSearch(string sortingProps, int pageSize, int startIndex, string filter, IEnumerable<string> selectedPropList)
    {
        string url = "_api/search/postquery";
        List<dynamic> sortedPropList = new List<dynamic>();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortingProps))
        {
            foreach (string prop in sortingProps.Split(','))
            {
                string tempProp = prop.Trim();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempProp))
                {
                    var r = tempProp.Split(':');
                    sortedPropList.Add(
                         new
                         {
                             //__metadata = new { type= "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.Sort" },
                             Property = r[0],
                             Direction = r.Length > 1 ? (r[1].ToLower() == "ascending" ? '0' : '1' ) : '0'
                         }
                        );
                }
            }
        }
        string internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + url;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());

        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;

        dynamic queryObject = new ExpandoObject();
        queryObject.Querytext = filter;
        queryObject.TrimDuplicates = false;
        queryObject.EnableFQL = true;

        queryObject.SourceId = "e6fc9815-a1b1-410a-81ac-1a0056a44f00";

        //queryObject.SourceId = "e7ec8cee-ded8-43c9-beb5-436b54b31e84";

        queryObject.ClientType = "WebService";
        queryObject.StartRow = startIndex;
        queryObject.RowLimit = pageSize;
        if (!selectedPropList.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            queryObject.SelectProperties = new
            {
                results = selectedPropList
            };
        }

        if (sortedPropList.Count > 0)
        {
            queryObject.SortList = new
            {
                results = sortedPropList
            };
        }

        dynamic requestBody = new
        {
            request = queryObject
        };

        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8";
        request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", GetFormDigest(credentials.baseUrl(), credential, cookie));

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse responseInternal = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseInternal.GetResponseStream());
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected String SPListAttachments(Guid type, int pageSize, int startIndex, int id)
    {
        string url = String.Format("_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/items", type);
        string internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + url;
        internalUrl += "?$filter=ID eq " + id.ToString() + "&$select=&selectedProps='Attachments,AttachmentFiles'&$expand=AttachmentFiles";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Accept = @"application/json;odata=verbose";
        HttpWebResponse responseInternal = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseInternal.GetResponseStream());
        var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return objText;
    }

    protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SPGetAttachment(String type, int id, string fileName, HttpRequestMessage Request)
    {
        var internalUrl = "/lists/" + type + "/Attachments/" + id + "/" + fileName;
        return await SPGetAttachment(Request, internalUrl);
    }

    protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SPGetAttachment(HttpRequestMessage Request, string internalUrl)
    {
        //prevent path trasversal
        if (internalUrl.Contains(".."))
            throw new HttpException(500, "");
        internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + internalUrl;
        try
        {
            NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
            CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
            {
                { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
            };
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Credentials = credentialCache
            };
            CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
            {
                string absoluteUrl = internalUrl;
                var proxyRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(Request.Method, absoluteUrl);
                proxyRequest.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", GetFormDigest(credentials.baseUrl(), credential, cookie));
                var res = await httpClient.SendAsync(proxyRequest);
                res.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
                //TOTEST!
                /*res.Headers.Remove("Content-Disposition");
                Uri uri = new Uri(internalUrl);
                string filename=string.Empty;
                var values = new List<String>() { "inline" };
                if (uri.IsFile) {
                    values.Add(String.Format("filename={0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath)));
                }
                res.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", values);*/
                return res;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Exception " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SPSaveAttachment(Guid type, int id, HttpRequestMessage Request)
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        var filename = String.Empty;
        byte[] fileArray = null;
        foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
        {
            filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
            fileArray = file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            //Unclear: Why do we iterate the entire collection and take only the last one?
            if (!(CheckLengthFileName(filename) && CheckFileType(filename) && CheckContentType(file.Headers.ContentType)))
            {
                throw new HttpException(415, "File not accepted by WKPortal");
            }
        }
        string url = String.Format("_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/items({1})/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='{2}')", type, id, filename);
        string internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + url;
        //prevent path trasversal
        if (internalUrl.Contains(".."))
            throw new HttpException(500, "");
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", GetFormDigest(credentials.baseUrl(), credential, cookie));
        request.ContentLength = fileArray.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(fileArray, 0, fileArray.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        HttpWebResponse responseInternal = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseInternal.GetResponseStream());
        var xmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlText))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            ns.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
            doc.LoadXml(xmlText);

            string internalId = String.Empty;
            foreach (XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("//d:ID", ns))
            {
                internalId = row.InnerXml;
            }
            var result = new { id = internalId };
            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }
        return response;
    }

    private bool CheckLengthFileName(string filename)
    {
        return filename.Length <= MAX_LENGTH_FILENAME;
    }

    private bool CheckFileType(string filename)
    {
        return !ProhibitedFileExtensions.Contains(new FileInfo(filename).Extension.Replace(".", string.Empty));
    }

    private bool CheckContentType(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType)
    {
        //TODO: when I get a list of insecure mime types I will complete this here.
        //meanwhile the extension filter should block most of the stuff
        return true;
    }

    protected RestResponse DeleteAttachment(Guid type, int id, string fileName)
    {
        string url = String.Format("_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/items({1})/AttachmentFiles/getByFileName(FileName='{2}')", type, id, fileName);
        string internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + url;
        //prevent path trasversal
        if (internalUrl.Contains(".."))
            throw new HttpException(500, "");
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", GetFormDigest(credentials.baseUrl(), credential, cookie));
        request.Method = "DELETE";
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        HttpWebResponse responseInternal = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseInternal.GetResponseStream());
        var xmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlText))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            ns.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
            doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
            string internalId = String.Empty;
            foreach (XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("//d:ID", ns))
            {
                internalId = row.InnerXml;
            }
            var result = new { id = internalId };
            return Ok(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        }
        return Ok();
    }

    protected String SPGetItem(Guid type, int id)
    {
        string url = String.Format("_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/items", type);
        string internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + url;
        internalUrl += "?$filter=ID eq " + id.ToString();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Accept = @"application/json;odata=verbose";
        HttpWebResponse responseInternal = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseInternal.GetResponseStream());
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    protected RestResponse SPSave(Guid type, string json, bool isNew, int id)
    {
        string url = String.Empty;
        if (isNew)
        {
            url = String.Format("_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/items", type);
        }
        else
        {
            url = String.Format("_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/items({1})", type, id);
        }
        string internalUrl = credentials.baseUrl() + url;
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(credentials.user(), credentials.password(), credentials.domain());
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internalUrl);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", GetFormDigest(credentials.baseUrl(), credential, cookie));
        request.ContentLength = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(json);
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        request.Method = "POST";
        if (!isNew)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
            request.Headers.Add("If-Match", "*");
        }
        request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8";
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            { new Uri(internalUrl), "NTLM", credential }
        };
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }
        HttpWebResponse responseInternal = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseInternal.GetResponseStream());
        var xmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlText))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            ns.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
            doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
            string internalId = String.Empty;
            foreach (XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("//d:ID", ns))
            {
                internalId = row.InnerXml;
            }
            var result = new { id = internalId };
            return Ok(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        }
        return Ok(); ;
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You're using Windows authentication which will fail in SPO. You should instead convert to using Graph APIs or classic SharePoint Client ID/Secret. I would start with these articles:

Classic CSOM development:

[Authorization and authentication of SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-and-authentication-of-sharepoint-add-ins)

You may also want to consider rebuilding your application in .NET Core:

[Using CSOM for .NET Standard instead of CSOM for .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard)

Modern Graph API development:

[Microsoft Graph auth overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)

[Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)